# samba access problem 18.04

Tags: samba

I have setup a samba server on 18.04 and run into a problem with access of sambashares

- user can access his home folder through samba (so I know the [samba]user exists, credentials are recognized)
- same user can **not** access any sambashare (even though user is in the group required, access rights are `774`)

smb.conf looks like this:

```
   [global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = no
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user

#============== Share definitions =======================


[samba]

    comment = Share for group Warehouse
    path = /srv/smb/samba/
    browseable = yes
    writeable = yes
    force create mode = 0660
    force directory mode = 0660
    Valid users = @sambausers
```

Any idea, what the root of this trouble may be?

Comment: Run "ls -dl /srv/smb/samba". What group is displayed? If it's not sambausers the remote user will not gain access. So either change the group ownership of the folder or set permissions to 777.

Comment: thx @Morbius1: that actually showed a 'good' group. solution came with the group of the parent/base folder (see below)

Answer (score 1):

apparently the group of the parent folder of the share (`/srv/smb` in my case) **does** actually matter.

changing that to `sambashare` (which all my samba users are members off) fixed this issue.

Comment: Nope. What does matter is if members of the sambashare group can traverse the /srv/smb folder to get to the /samba folder. So regardless of the group of /srv/smb sambashare members would get access to /samba if the permissions of /srv/smb were 755, 775, 777, or even 711. But not 700, 770, or this curious 774 you are using since the "4" disables the traversal unless the group matches.