# Samba 4.7.6 Issues on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, permissions, 18.04, samba, file-sharing

I have been hosting a few public and access-controlled shared folders (located on an external drive) using Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu under Ubuntu 14.04.  That worked very well, and exactly as desired for my small office.

The machine running 14.04 crashed, so I replaced it with a newer machine, upon which I installed Ubuntu 18.04, and the latest version of Samba available from `apt`, which is Samba 4.7.6-Ubuntu.

Now, the same `smb.conf` file that worked flawlessly on my Ubuntu 14.04/Samba 4.3.11 setup does **not** work on my 18.04 setup.

In fact, the **only** way I can get any Samba users to have any access at all is if I make them an admin user in the `smb.conf` file, so the `admin users` definition in the `[global]` section in the conf file below was previously commented out.  It is uncommented to allow my users access, as described.

I have already tried making the `[global]` section minimalistic, bringing it down to a log file definition only.

What could be happening?  Here's the conf file:

```
# Samba config file
# From UNKNOWN
# Date: 2018/01/01 00:01:26

[global]
    workgroup = safeserver
    netbios name = safeserver
    server string = SAFE File Server: %L
    #interfaces = eth0, lo, wlan0
    inherit acls = Yes
    inherit permissions = Yes
    dns proxy = no
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    unix password sync = Yes

    admin users = drusmor, jadams, bfranklin, gwashington, ugrant
    #admin users = drusmor
    invalid users = ccoolidge

    log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
    log level = 1 winbind:5
    max log size = 1000

    #smb ports = 139
    #name resolve order = bcast lmhosts host wins
    logon path = \\safeserver\profiles\.msprofile
    logon drive = P:
    logon home = \\safeserver\%U\.9xprofile

    # Makes this box the master file server
    #os level = 254
    #preferred master = No
    #domain master = Yes
    wins support = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    # nodelay is default, increasing buf size helps speed, keepalive closes
    # dead connections and returns memory to system.
    #socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536 SO_KEEPALIVE
    # Set to cleanup dead connections quickly
    deadtime = 15

    load printers = no
    printable = no

[homes]
    # Added by DAR on 8 Feb 2018
    comment = Home Directories (on external shared drive)
    #invalid users = root, bin, daemon, nobody, named, sys, tty, disk, mem, kmem
    valid users = %S
    path = /media/safeserver/externaldrive/homes/%U
    read only = no
    guest ok = no
    create mask = 0700
    directory mask = 0700
    store dos attributes = yes
    browseable = no

[nbackup]
    # Added by DAR on 15 Feb 2018
    comment = Local Backup
    #invalid users = root, bin, daemon, nobody, named, sys, tty, disk, mem, kmem
    valid users = drusmor
    path = /media/safeserver/LOCAL_BACKUP
    read only = no
    guest ok = no
    create mask = 0700
    directory mask = 0700
    store dos attributes = yes
    browseable = no

[profiles]
    comment = Network Profiles Service
    path = %H
    read only = no
    guest ok = no
    create mask = 0600
    directory mask = 0700
    store dos attributes = yes
    browseable = no

#[printers]
#       comment = All Printers
#       path = /var/spool/samba
#       create mask = 0700
#       printable = yes
#       browseable = no
#
#[print$]
#       comment = Printer Drivers
#       path = /var/lib/samba/printers

[shared]
    comment = SAFE Shared Directories
    path = /media/safeserver/externaldrive/serve
    invalid users = root, bin, daemon, nobody, named, sys, tty, disk, mem, kmem
    valid users = @users
    read only = no
    guest ok = no
    create mode = 0664
    directory mode = 0770
    #inherit acls = yes
    writeable = yes

[Training]
    comment = SAFE Training Materials
    path = /media/safeserver/externaldrive/serve/Training
    #valid users = drusmor, gwashington, ugrant
    valid users = @Exec
    invalid users = jadams, bfranklin
    force group = Exec
    read only = no
    guest ok = no
    browseable = yes
    public = no
    create mode = 0664
    directory mode = 0770
    inherit acls = yes
    writeable = yes

[Recipes]
    comment = SAFE Recipes
    path = /media/safeserver/externaldrive/serve/Recipes
    #valid users = drusmor, gwashington, ugrant
    valid users = @Recipes
    invalid users = jadams, bfranklin
    force group = Recipes
    read only = no
    guest ok = no
    browseable = yes
    public = no
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 0770
    inherit acls = yes
    Writeable = yes

[Transferral]
    comment = CEO Transfer
    path = /media/safeserver/externaldrive/Transferral
    valid users = @ceotransfer
    invalid users = gwashington, ugrant, jadams, bfranklin
    force group = ceotransfer
    read only = no
    guest ok = no
    browsable = yes
    public = no
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 0770
    inherit acls = yes
    Writable = yes
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I should add that I have already referenced the question asked here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031101/samba-access-problem-18-04
But this does not correct the issue for me.

Comment: More than likely some of the default samba settings changed. You would need to explicitly set the settings in your 'new' `smb.conf`. Locating the changes is where the real fun happens.

Comment: Smart suggestion.  I went through that exercise, using `testparm -vs`, and actually compared it against a backup of my old 14.04 system, but it unfortunately proved fruitless (not saying I didn't miss something, of course).  There were differences, indeed, but aligning my new rig to my old rig made no difference.  Am I missing something as far as this version of Samba?